# Python function using loops

Tags: python

I need help going through this problem

> print the list elements in reverse order using a loop

`def reverse():
nums = [3,7,5,0,-4,1,0,-7,34,5,-87,43,1,76]`

we cannot use reverse command and must use loops.

Comment: make an attempt. give it a sincere try first. This isn't a place to get your homework done for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
nums = [3,7,5,0,-4,1,0,-7,34,5,-87,43,1,76]

for i in range(len(nums)-1, -1, -1):
    print(nums[i])
```

This basically starts with 1 less than `len(nums)`, goes until you get to just before -1, in increments of -1.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you'll need a for loop. You can use the `range()` function to go through your list indexes, like this:

`range(len(nums) - 1, -1, -1)`

The first argument, 'len(nums) - 1', just means that it'll run the loop for the same amount of times as the number of elements in the list.

The second argument, '-1', means that it'll start from the end of the list, and count down.

The third argument, also '-1', means that it'll count down instead of up.

So your for loop initialisation will look like this:
`for i in range(len(nums) - 1, -1, -1):`

Now, you need to print the numbers. In any given iteration, `i` will refer to the index of the currently selected element. To print an element of a list with an index, the syntax is `list[index]`. So, our code inside the loop will be:

`print(nums[i])`

All put together, the final code for the loop is this:

```
for i in range(len(nums) - 1, -1, -1):
    print(nums[i])
```

That's all the code you need to solve your problem.
Hope this helps,
Dan.